# Is there a way to download a file from sharepoint, edit it and uploading back up within the application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm developing an app c#(winforms) that can open a xml file from your computer, edit it(delete nodes, add new ones and change existing ones) and of course saving it to your computer again.

That xml file is uploaded to a sharepoint 2007 library in our site.
So i want to save the trouble of saving the file on the pc and then uploading it manually.

Is there a way that instead of open the file locally, it could just download the same file from a sharepoint library and open it up for editing and then saving the changes to the file in the library?

Using Visual Studio Ultimate 2010, the app is using .net 3.5

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have [M$ demo app](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Sharepoint-2007-File-396ec8f0) which can download/upload files to SP2007. Most important parts:

Download:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(txtSite.Text)) 
            { 
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()) 
                { 
                    SPFolder myLibrary = web.Folders[txtDocLib.Text]; 

                    foreach (SPFile file in myLibrary.Files) 
                    { 
                        if (file.Name == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()) 
                        { 
                            byte[] bytes = file.OpenBinary(); 

                            try 
                            { 
                                FileStream fs = new FileStream(dialog.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite); 
                                BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs); 
                                bw.Write(bytes); 
                                bw.Close(); 
                                MessageBox.Show("File downloaded to: " + dialog.FileName); 
                            } 
                            catch (Exception ex) 
                            { 
                                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
                            } 

                        }                             
                    } 
                } 
            }
```

Upload:

```
using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(txtSite.Text)) 
        { 
            using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb()) 
            {                     
                SPFolder myLibrary = oWeb.Folders[txtDocLib.Text]; 

                // Prepare to upload 
                Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true; 
                String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(txtSelectedFile.Text); 
                FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(txtSelectedFile.Text); 

                // Upload document 
                SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFiles); 

                // Commit  
                myLibrary.Update(); 
            } 
        }
```